# Убрать определенные элементы словарей объединенных в список

Tags: python

Есть задача убрать из словарей элементы с ключом 'key1' вот таким образом:

Original List:

```
[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key1': 'value3', 'key2': 'value4'}]
```

New List:

```
[{'key2': 'value2'}, {'key2': 'value4'}]
```

Есть вот такое решение:

```
l = [{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}, {'key1':'value3', 'key2':'value4'}]
l1 = [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k != 'key1'} for d in original_list]
l1


[{'key2': 'value2'}, {'key2': 'value4'}]
```

мне не понятен вот этот кусок кода: '[{k: v'.
С целью разобраться я попытался преобразовать List comprehesion в nested loops:

```
def func(l):
li = []
d = {}
for i in l:
    for k,v in i.items():
        if k != 'key1':
            d[k] = v
    li.append(d)
return li
            
l = [{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}, {'key1':'value3', 'key2':'value4'}]   
func(l)
```

Вот что получилось:

```
[{'key2': 'value4'}, {'key2': 'value4'}]
```

Вопрос:

1. где ошибка?
2. Что значит '[{k: v' в первом варианте и как этот участок кода преобразовать в обычный цикл?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

Ошибка в том, что вы используете переменную `d` много раз и не очищаете её. Вот верный код:

```
def func(l):
    li = []
    for i in l:
        d = {}
        for k,v in i.items():
            if k != 'key1':
                d[k] = v
        li.append(d)
    return li
```

В остальном ваше преобразование верно. Фрагмент `k: v` означает просто конструкцию `ключ: значение` (`key: value`), которую вы заменили строкой `d[k] = v`.

Comment: это я понимаю, мне не понятно как этот фрагмент использовать в моем решении вместо d[k] = v. Или мой первоначальный вариант единственно возможный? Имею в виду добавление элемента k:v в словарь. Т.е. можно использовать во втором решении k:v вместо d[k] = v каким либо образом?

Comment: @nich123 это равнозначные конструкции.

Comment: да но как в коде это использовать во втором варианте? я пробовал у меня получилась ошибка

Comment: В смысле как? Мой код (то есть измененный ваш) делает все то же самое, что и генератор. Это равнозначные конструкции и ничего более менять не надо.

Comment: если они равнозначные значит можно использовать в вашем коде фрагмент k:v вместо d[k] = v? Я  не понимаю, почему в первом варианте Python понимает что в словарь нужно добавить пару k:v а в цикле нужно использовать конструкцию d[k] = v и никак иначе. Или все-таки есть вариант добавить в список элементы другим способом используя конструкцию k:v?

Comment: Это конструкция, свойственная только генераторам. Как можно не использовать генераторы и при этом пытаться использовать конструкцию, только им свойственную?

Comment: иначе говоря если для добавления элемента в словарь мы используем конструкцию d[k] = v, то в случае с list comprehesion мы по идее должны использовать вот такой вариант: new_list = [{d[k] = v for k, v in d.items() if k != 'key1'} for d in original_list]. Тем не менее мы просто пишем k:v. Вот мне что не понятно

Comment: @nich123 советую подробнее изучить материалы по генераторам словарей: https://habr.com/ru/post/224163/

Answer (score 4):

если нужно модифицировать исходный список, а не получить другую копию, то можно
пойти другим путем - удалять из исходных словарей ненужный ключ

```
dict_list = [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key1': 'value1', 'key3': 'value3'}]
for dict_item in dict_list:
    dict_item.pop('key1', None)
```